# Spring CLoud Gateway custom redirection filter does not work

Tags: spring-boot, routes, microservices, spring-cloud-gateway

I am building a little project about an e-commerce with Spring Boot using a microservices architecture. I have the following services implemented and working: User , Product, Order , ApiGateway.

user service port: 8082
apiGateway service port: 8080

Inside the ApiGateway service I am using spring cloud gateway for routing , this is the configuration file:

```
`@Configuration
public class GatewayRouteConfig {

    @Value("${com.service.user.url}")
    private String user_url ;
    
    
    @Value("${com.service.product.url}")
    private String product_url ;
    
    @Value("${com.service.order.url}")
    private String order_url ;
    
    
     @Bean
     public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
         return builder.routes()
                 // All of these routes have to be authenticated
                 .route("user-service", r -> r.path("/user/**")
                         .filters(w -> w.rewritePath("/user/(?<segment>/?.*)", "/api/user/$\\{segment}")
                         )
                         .uri(user_url)
                         )
                 .route("only-auth", r -> r.path("/auth/**")
                         //TODO escludere /auth/login e /auth/logout
                         .filters(w ->  w.rewritePath("/auth/(?<segment>/?.*)", "/api/auth/$\\{segment}")
//                               .filter(new UserAuthenticationFilter().apply(new UserAuthentication()))
                                 )
                         .uri(user_url)
                         )
                 .route("order", r -> r.path("/order/**")
                         .filters(w -> w.rewritePath("/order/(?<segment>/?.*)", "/api/order/$\\{segment}")
                                 .filter(new UserAuthenticationFilter().apply(new UserAuthentication()))
                         )
                         .uri(order_url)     
                         )
                 .route("cart", r -> r.path("/cart/**")
                         .filters(w -> w.rewritePath("/cart/(?<segment>/?.*)", "/api/cart/$\\{segment}")
                                 .filter(new UserAuthenticationFilter().apply(new UserAuthentication()))
                         )
                         .uri(order_url)     
                         )
                 .route("inventory", r -> r.path("/product/**")
                         .filters(w -> w.rewritePath("/product/(?<segment>/?.*)", "/api/product/$\\{segment}")
                         )
                         .uri(product_url)   
                         )
                         
                         /* implement role based routes for admins and users
                          * eg: /api/product/showAll -> no auth 
                          *    /api/product/(create/update/delete) -> admin
                          *    /api/product/(decrease/increaseQUantity) -> auth
                          */
                         
                         .build();
                 
     }


    
}
`
```

I want that only users with a valid session cookie (generated into the User Service) can access specific routes like the route "order" so I implemented the following custom filter to create some logic :

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class UserAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<UserAuthentication> {

    public UserAuthenticationFilter() {
        super(UserAuthentication.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(UserAuthentication authenticator) {

        return (exchange, chain) -> {

            boolean areCookiesPresent = authenticator.areCookiesPresent(exchange);
            boolean areCookiesValid = authenticator.areCookiesValid(exchange);
            
            if (areCookiesPresent == false || areCookiesValid == false) {
                log.info("session authentication through cookies : NOT OK -> redirecting");
                URI redirectUri;
                                            
                redirectUri = URI.create("http://localhost:8080/user/loginPage");
                
                ServerHttpRequest request = exchange
                        .getRequest()
                        .mutate()
                        .uri(redirectUri)
                        .method(HttpMethod.GET)
                        .build();
                
                
                ServerWebExchange mutatedExchange = exchange
                        .mutate()
                        .request(request)
                        .build();
                
                log.info(request.getURI().toString());

                mutatedExchange.getAttributes().put(GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR, request.getURI());
                
                return chain.filter(mutatedExchange);
                
            }

            log.info("session authentication through cookies : OK");
            return chain.filter(exchange);
            
        };

    }

    
}
```

If the cookies representing the user role and user id are not provided into the request the user should be redirected to a login page located into the User service, (the user/loginPage returns only a string stating "Login Page": this is done because this is a internship project where I am not actually interested in creating a front end)

my problem is with this custom filter, when I try to access a route without the cookies I get a 404 like this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-03-30T10:18:13.550+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/user/loginPage"
}
```

Can someone help me with this?

I am expecting to get a String like "this is the login page, welcome"